# AS3 collision with an eventual object

Tags: actionscript-3, object, collision

I still did not understand what to do in situations like this...

I'm trying to develop a simple maze game where you can't touch the walls or you'll lose.

I've created a player class and added a child of it using `stage.addChild(player)` in a Main class.

I have also put a walls object graphically on the stage... When i run the game, it says of course that `walls is an undefined property`. Then how should I explain this "EVENTUAL" walls presence in the class Player --> `this.hitTestObject(XXX)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check collision in your main class

```
var player:Player;

var walls:Array;

function checkCollistion():void
{

     for each (var wall:YourWallClass in walls)
     {
         //here is the simplest wall to do check hitTestObject
         //you can optimize it
         if (player.hitTestObject(wall)
         {

         }

     }
}
```

Or you could keep a walls reference in your player class. So when you create a playe instance with the walls define in the main class.

```
 public class Player 
 {

     private var walls:Array;

     public function Player($walls:Array)
     {
          walls = $walls;
     }
 }
```